# Nested HashMap Object - Evaluating particular value to UpperCase

Tags: java, json, jackson, hashmap, gson

[image: Below mentioned HashMap]

Wanted to convert all direction value to **upper case**

Or if we have better way to do it in JSON Object itself, converting all direction value to **upper case**

```
    {
    "query": {
        "select": {...},
        "where": {...},
        "orderBy": [
            {
                "key": "item.id",
                "direction": "asc"
            },
            {
                "key": "page.id",
                "direction": "desc"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Tried Solution:

```
`private static JSONObject uppercaseDirection(JSONObject json) throws JSONException
{
    Iterator<?> keys = json.keys();
    while (keys.hasNext())
    {
        String k = (String) keys.next();
        if (JSON_PROPERTY_DIRECTION.equals(k))
        {
            json.put(JSON_PROPERTY_DIRECTION, json.get(JSON_PROPERTY_DIRECTION).toString().toUpperCase());
        }
        Object value = json.opt(k);
        if (value != null && value instanceof JSONObject)
        {
            uppercaseDirection((JSONObject) value);
        } else if ("orderBy".equals(k) && value != null && value instanceof JSONArray)
        {
            for (Object ob : (JSONArray) value)
            {
                uppercaseDirection((JSONObject) ob);
            }
        }
    }
    return json;
}`
```

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko Mentioned above solution, but not that clean

Answer (score 0):

Whether it's a map or JSON the basic idea will be to iterate the key-value pairs and update the correct key with the new value.

Example with json:

```
String json = "{\"query\":{\"select\":{\"f1\":1},\"where\":{\"f1\":1},\"orderBy\":[{\"key\":\"item.id\",\"direction\":\"asc\"},{\"key\":\"page.id\",\"direction\":\"desc\"}]}}";
JsonObject jsonObject = JsonParser.parseString(json).getAsJsonObject();
JsonArray jsonArray = jsonObject.get("query").getAsJsonObject().get("orderBy").getAsJsonArray();
Iterator<JsonElement> itr = jsonArray.iterator();
while(itr.hasNext()) {
    JsonObject obj = itr.next().getAsJsonObject();          
    obj.addProperty("direction", obj.get("direction").getAsString().toUpperCase());
}

System.out.println(jsonObject);
```

Output

```
{"query":{"select":{"f1":1},"where":{"f1":1},"orderBy":[{"key":"item.id","direction":"ASC"},{"key":"page.id","direction":"DESC"}]}}
```

Comment: Yeah, It can work  with few null checks, but Is there any other better solution. Like library supporting methods.

Comment: @DeepakDhaka What do you mean by `library supporting methods`?  Are you looking for any method which will update the JSON with a new value for a certain key?  I don't think that kind of method exists at least not to my knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/octomix/josson
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.octomix.josson/josson

```
Josson josson = Josson.fromJsonString("{\"query\":{\"select\":{\"f1\":1},\"where\":{\"f1\":1},\"orderBy\":[{\"key\":\"item.id\",\"direction\":\"asc\"},{\"key\":\"page.id\",\"direction\":\"desc\"}]}}");
JsonNode node = josson.getNode("field(query.field(orderBy.field(direction.upperCase())))");
System.out.println(node.toPrettyString());
```

Output

```
{
  "query" : {
    "select" : {
      "f1" : 1
    },
    "where" : {
      "f1" : 1
    },
    "orderBy" : [ {
      "key" : "item.id",
      "direction" : "ASC"
    }, {
      "key" : "page.id",
      "direction" : "DESC"
    } ]
  }
}
```